# Understanding maths in adanet paper

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am reading up on adanet from [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.01097.pdf)

In the network architecture section the author defines it as

let $l$ denote the number of intermediate layers in the network and $n_k$ the maximum number of units in layer $k \in [l]$. Each unit $j \in [n_k]$ in layer $k$ represents a function denoted by $h_{k,j}$ (before composition with an activation function). let $X$ denote the input space and for any $x \in X$, let $\Psi(x) \in R^{n_{0}}$ denote the corresponding feature vector. Then the family of functions defined by the first layer functions $h_{1,j}, j \in [n_1]$, is the following

$$H_1 = \left\{x \mapsto \displaystyle\sum_{s=1}^{k-1}{\bf{u}}.\Psi(x): {\bf{u}} \in \mathbb{R}^{n_{0}}, {||{{\bf{u}}}||}_p \leq \Lambda_{1,0}\right\} \tag1$$

Hence, $H_1$ is a set of all the linear mappings of input feature vector

Where $p \geq 1$ defines an $l_p$ norm and $\Lambda_{1,0} \geq 0$ is a hyperparameter on the weights connecting layer 0 and layer 1. The family of functions $h_{k,j}, j\in [n_k]$, in a higher layer $k > 1$ is then defined as follows

$$H_k = \left\{x \mapsto \displaystyle\sum_{s=1}^{k-1}{\bf{u}_s}.(\psi_s \circ {\bf{h}_s})(x): {\bf{u}}_s \in \mathbb{R}^{n_{s}}, {||{{\bf{u}}_s}||}_p \leq \Lambda_{k,s}, h_{k,s} \in H_s \right\}\tag2$$

$ \circ$ denotes a element wise composition with a Non-linearity. ReLU, sigmoid etc. $\Lambda$ defines how sparse the network would be. Basically regularization

Hence, $H_k$ is a set of all the linear mappings of all the feature maps (vector of outputs) produced by all previous layers

This basically defines an architecture where $H_k$ is the $k^{th}$ layer and is connected to every layer that comes before the $k^{th}$ layer

Now the final definition. output unit of the network is defined as a function $$\displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^{l}\sum_{j=1}^{n_k}}w_{k,j}h_{k,j} = \sum_{k=1}^{l}{\bf{w}}_k{\bf{h}}_k \tag 3$$ where $\bf{h_k}$ is the output vector of $k_{th}$ layer and ${\bf{w_k}}\in\mathbb{R}^{n_k}$ is the vector of connecting weights to units of layer $k$

Then the author goes on to define $\mathcal{F}$ the family of functions defined by **equation (3)** with the absolute value of the weights summing to one: $$\mathcal{F} = \left\{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{l}{\bf{w_k}}.{\bf{h_k}}:h_k \in {H_{k}^{{n}_{k}}}, \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^l||W_k|| = 1 \right\}$$

Let $\widetilde{H_k}$ denote the union of $H_k$ and its reflection, $\widetilde{H_k}= H_k \bigcup (-H_k)$ and let $H$ denote the union of families $\widetilde{H_k}: H = \bigcup_{k=1}^l\widetilde{H_k}$. Then, $\mathcal{F}$ coincides with the convex hull of $H: \mathcal{F} = conv(H)$.

I do not understand how

1. $\mathcal{F}$ coincides with the convex hull of $H: \mathcal{F} = conv(H)$. Is $H_k$ not already its own reflection since it is the set of all possible linear mappings. So why is not $\widetilde{H_k}$ = $H_k$ = $-H_k$?
2. This mathematical representation of the network architecture here allows for biases to be included in various layers

Comment: The convex hull is the set of all convex combinations (linear combinations where the weights sum up to one and each weight is positive). $\mathcal{F}$ is by definition the affine hull of all the $H_k$ sets, because you've not disallowed negative weights, only constrained their sum to one. When you add the negative sets $(-H_k)$ to the union the convex hull of those sets now coincides with the affine hull of $\bigcup_{k}H_k$ hence it coincides with $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: @gcc-6.0 Thank you friend. I have a small followup. I read on convex combinations and i get that $\mathcal{F}$ is going to be the convex hull of $H_k$ if i had disallowed negative weights. However reading your comment i get the immpression that $\mathcal{F}$ is the convex hull of all $H_k$ because i have not disallowed negative weights. Please clarify the confusion

Comment: I said that $\mathcal{F}$ is the **affine hull** of $\bigcup_k H_k$, which is all linear combinations with weight summing up to $1$ (negative weights are ok here). So now taking the **convex hull** of $\bigcup_k H_k$ won't give you $\mathcal{F}$. But adding the negated elements of $H_k$ to the union $\bigcup_k (H_k \cup (-H_k))$ and taking the **convex hull** (no negative weights) of that now does the job because if you had combination containing negative element it's as if you had negative weight with the positive element from your original $H_k$.

Comment: @gcc-6.0 - Got it. Layman on this end stands cleared of his doubts. Thank you. If you add this as answer i would accept it